# Latest Flash Update brings in bugs in interaction

Tags: flash-player, adobe-flash

I installed the latest update for Adobe Flash Player some days ago, and I have been experiencing difficulties on several sites that run Flash. Can't control the video playback in Youtube, can't scroll the pages properly on Safari Books, can't play embedded youtube videos.

Is it just me or is this a bug? How to fix this?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ and tell us what it says. I'm using 10.1.82.76 and didn't have any problems with it since I updated. As far as I know, there wasn't any official release in maybe a month or more.

Could it be a virus trying to pass itself as flash?

Comment: mine also says version 10.1.82.76 installed, but I have been experiencing problems on my Mac at home as well as Windows XP pc at work.

Comment: @ShiVik Sorry, I don't have any real idea what could the problem be.

Comment: It seems like flash is giving problems on Chrome. Maybe I can try reinstalling on Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution in another question of mine http://superuser.com/questions/192164/flash-not-working-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

In case the update has simply gone bad, you could uninstall and reinstall Flash.

Be sure to scan for viruses after the uninstallation, and to download the latest Flash, straight from Adobe.