# Flash not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash-player, adobe-flash

I have been experiencing problems in using Flash on Google Chrome on Mac. I have updated to Google Chrome version 6.0. I checked that my flash version is 10.1.83.5. Since it is Google Chrome on Mac that is why the flash player is built-in.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot install Adobe air apps like one over [here](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/download), Youtube doesn't work properly specially volume controls, basically websites with embedded flash files which require any kind of interaction with mouse do not work.

The same websites on Firefox work ok. Google Chrome on Windows doesn't give any problems either. Its just the Google Chrome on Mac.

Has been anybody else been experiencing the same problem? Is there a solution?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this will help as it appears you are seeing a few things in Youtube.

If you want to check that Adobe Flash is enabled correctly, type `chrome://plugins/` to the address bar.

Click the `+ Details` option to expand each section.

Look for the section on Flash and you should be able to enable/disable both the system flash (located in a shared folder) and your Chrome flash. I would recommend playing around with these options - possibly if it is causing problems, disable the Chrome flash and enable your system one.

[image]

Chrome settings on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I disabled the system Flash from inside the Chrome Plugins Manager and that worked for me. :)

Comment: This has again started giving the same problem. Can't seem to get it working now. Seems like it only worked the first time.